# Created an IP monitor in excel using VBA. Need to ping the main IP and then two failover IP's

Tags: excel, vba

I have created an IP monitor in excel using VBA. Main IP is in column J, first fail over in column M and second fail over in column P. I am able to activate the script for each column individually. How can I change the script to ping left to right, move down one line and ping again left to right using one button only.

```
Sub Ping()
    
    Sheet1.Range("K8:K952").Clear
    Dim hostIp1 As String
    For i = 8 To Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    
            
    hostIp1 = Sheet1.Cells(i, 10).Value
    If Not hostIp1 = "" Then
    Dim objShell1, returnCode1
    
    Set objShell1 = CreateObject("wscript.shell")
            returnCode1 = objShell1.Run("Ping -n 1 -w 1000 " & hostIp1, 0, True)
    
    If returnCode1 = 0 Then
                Sheet1.Cells(i, 11).Value = "Online"
                Sheet1.Cells(i, 11).Font.Color = vbGreen
                Sheet1.Cells(i, 12).Value = Now
            Else
                Sheet1.Cells(i, 11).Value = "Offline"
                Sheet1.Cells(i, 11).Font.Color = vbRed
    End If
    End If
    Next

End Sub

Sub Ping2()

    Sheet1.Range("N8:N952").Clear
    Dim hostIp2 As String
    For j = 8 To Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    
            
    hostIp2 = Sheet1.Cells(j, 13).Value
    If Not hostIp2 = "" Then
    Dim objShell2, returnCode2
    
    Set objShell2 = CreateObject("wscript.shell")
            returnCode2 = objShell2.Run("Ping -n 1 -w 1000 " & hostIp2, 0, True)
    
    If returnCode2 = 0 Then
                Sheet1.Cells(j, 14).Value = "Online"
                Sheet1.Cells(j, 14).Font.Color = vbGreen
                Sheet1.Cells(j, 15).Value = Now
        
            Else
                Sheet1.Cells(j, 14).Value = "Offline"
                Sheet1.Cells(j, 14).Font.Color = vbRed
                
    End If
    End If

Next

End Sub

Sub Ping3()

    Sheet1.Range("Q8:Q952").Clear
    Dim hostIp3 As String
    For k = 8 To Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        
        
    hostIp3 = Sheet1.Cells(k, 16).Value
    If Not hostIp3 = "" Then
    Dim objShell3, returnCode3
            
    Set objShell3 = CreateObject("wscript.shell")
            returnCode3 = objShell3.Run("Ping -n 1 -w 1000 " & hostIp3, 0, True)
            
            
    If returnCode3 = 0 Then
                Sheet1.Cells(k, 17).Value = "Online"
                Sheet1.Cells(k, 17).Font.Color = vbGreen
                Sheet1.Cells(k, 18).Value = Now
    
            Else
                Sheet1.Cells(k, 17).Value = "Offline"
                Sheet1.Cells(k, 17).Font.Color = vbRed
            End If
            End If

        Next

End Sub
```

Comment: "I have created an IP monitor in excel" - why?!?

Comment: @MitchWheat Haha, Why not?

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a parameter (Column to start with) and work with that.
See below code
`testPing` shows you how to call `Ping`

```vb
Sub testPing()
With sheet1
    Ping .Columns("K").Column
    Ping .Columns("Q").Column
End With
End Sub

Sub Ping(columnLetter As String)
    
    Dim colStart As Long, i As Long
    With sheet1
        colStart = .Columns(columnLetter).Column
        .Cells(8, colStart).Resize(945).Clear
        
        Dim hostIP1 As String
        For i = 8 To .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
            hostIP1 = .Cells(i, colStart - 1).Value
            If Not hostIP1 = "" Then
                Dim objShell1, returnCode1
                
                Set objShell1 = CreateObject("wscript.shell")
                        returnCode1 = objShell1.Run("Ping -n 1 -w 1000 " & hostIP1, 0, True)
                
                If returnCode1 = 0 Then
                    With .Cells(i, colStart)
                        .Value = "Online"
                        .Font.Color = vbGreen
                    End With
                    .Cells(i, colStart + 1).Value = Now
                Else
                    With .Cells(i, colStart)
                        .Value = "Offline"
                        .Font.Color = vbRed
                    End With
                End If
            End If
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```